# How do I get the batch size of a Tensorflow Prefetch/Cache Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I use `.batch()` as the last operation on a `tf.data.Dataset`, I can get the batch size like this:

```
train_ds._batch_size.numpy()
```

For instance with this dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(8)

train_ds._batch_size.numpy()
```

```
8
```

However, when I use `.batch().prefetch(1)`, I cannot get the batch size:

> AttributeError: 'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute '_batch_size'

Answer (score 2):

With any type of Tensorflow Dataset, you can access any dataset before the chained methods with `._input_dataset`:

```
train_ds._input_dataset
```

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 28, 28), (None,)), types: (tf.uint8, tf.uint8)>
```

Now that you have accessed the `BatchDataset` object, you can get the batch size the same way:

```
train_ds._input_dataset._batch_size.numpy()
```

```
8
```

The same would work for several transformations, e.g. `.batch().prefetch().cache()`:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))

train_ds = train_ds.batch(8).prefetch(1).cache()
```

```
train_ds._input_dataset._input_dataset._batch_size.numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your mean correctly, you want to get the batch size after you use the prefetch() method.

you can't get the **batch size**, however you can get the **buffer size** if that is what you want.

prefetch() method will give you a PrefetchDataset object, according to [the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L4467) of the PrefetchDataset Class.

```
 batch(8).prefetch(1)._buffer_size()
```

will do the job.